# obtaining data values on two different places within a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js, charts

[image]I have a chart in this [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/5D5eD/8/)

```
 var data = [

    [2,2],
    [3,3],
    [4,4],
    [5, 4],
    [5.5, 5],
    [6, 6],
    [6, 7],
    [4,5],
    [7,9],
    [7,10]
    ];
```

How do I put the datapoints above the chart and create a link between the chart above and the chart below. I want to link the datapoints on the chart below with those on the chart above. i.e. one data source plotting data on two quadrants above and below. The first chart(chart above) must have only datapoints without lines. How do I achieve this ?

Comment: Hi, it is not really clear what you are looking for here...could you perhaps generate a rough sketch to give us a better idea?

Comment: FernOfTheAndes its like this image http://www.image-share.com/ijpg-2493-30.html

Comment: FernOfTheAndes I have added the same code again at the bottom and translated y axis by 10  http://jsfiddle.net/5D5eD/16/. Is this the correct way ?

Comment: Excellent...good progress on your own. If you get rid of the x-axis in the new graph and place it right above the older graph with the lines, you will be pretty close to what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ygdKA/) that implements what I mentioned in my comments **with minimal changes to the code**. However, I strongly suggest that you re-arrange the current code. Basically, you want to find what is common in the construction of both charts and factor out the code. (Also, the current code order is inverted because you first started with the lower chart and then decided on a second one to be located above the first.)

```
var chart2 = d3.select('#nolines')
    .append('svg:svg')
    .attr('width', width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom/4)
    .attr('class', 'chart');
```

Comment: Thanks FernOfTheAndes. Thank you, you have helped me so much :)

Comment: FernOfTheAndes - How to add this projection http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3734327 in the chart on the top ? while the chart at the bottom remains same.

Comment: FernOfTheAndes - I want to get something like this http://www.d3noob.org/2013/03/a-simple-d3js-map-explained.html in place of the chart on the top. Please Guide me to achieve this.

Comment: FernOfTheAndes this link works in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ygdKA/ . But If I use it as html file it doesn't work. why ?

Comment: @user3438326 Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/EwzD4/) with the same code but as a complete html page. Does this help?

Comment: Yes FernOfTheAndes, thanks for helping. Thank you :)

Comment: FernOfTheAndes can you help me with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22837253/importing-data-from-two-csv-files-using-d3js?noredirect=1#comment34841945_22837253

Comment: @user3438326 I confirmed what Lars is saying...scroll your mouse when hovering over the output window and the 2nd chart will show up...there is a wide space between the 2 charts.

Comment: I'm able to see the output too. Now how to remove the wide space between the charts ?

Comment: @user3438326 Yes, there is an extra SVG in the middle: delete lines 192 to 202! Here is the new [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/urd3oIP0G2xwsTkSUTOx?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you so much FernOfTheAndes. There is a default datapoint at the origin when I open in the browser, how to avoid this ?