# Importing data from two csv files using d3js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, csv, d3.js

consider this fiddle link [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/EwzD4/). In this example I would like to use a csv file to load data at line no.33-[data.csv] and data at line no.158-[data1.csv]. I want to use two separate csv files. I tried using a csv file for data at line no.33 with this code

```
 d3.csv("data.csv", function(csvData) {

csvData.forEach(function (d,i) {
    data[i] = {
      first: +d.first, 
      second: +d.second
    } 
});
console.log(data);
```

I was able to get an output but the charts had moved far away from each other with the following errors : Unexpected value NaN parsing cy attribute. How to load the two datasets in an efficient way using two separate csv files ?

Comment: You would have to use `d3.csv` twice.

Comment: Yes Lars, but the chart is moved downwards i.e. the charts on top is distant from bottom chart by certain empty space,with this error:Unexpected value NaN parsing cy attribute.

Comment: I don't see that in your jsfiddle.

Comment: Its when I execute in my browser, and how to use a csv file in jsfiddle ?

Comment: You can use something like http://plnkr.co/ which allows you to have several files.

Comment: check this link Lars http://plnkr.co/edit/elgCmyKhK58uSDxhGj5D?p=info

Comment: You have spaces at the beginning of the lines in your CSV. Works without errors if you remove those -- http://plnkr.co/edit/vsNoQqmFAOdqVm9UPSaT?p=preview

Comment: Lars I don't see any difference after removing spaces in csv file, also in this link http://plnkr.co/edit/vsNoQqmFAOdqVm9UPSaT?p=preview I see only the top chart.

Comment: Both are there. The second one is a bit further down.

Comment: How to scroll down to the chart at the bottom ? there is no scroll option.

Comment: There should be a scroll bar...

Comment: There is a scroll bar only for the code but there is no scroll bar for output window

Comment: I really can't help you with that, it works fine for me.

Comment: I am able to see the ouput,I deleted the spaces in csv file but still there is an empty space between the charts Lars.

Comment: I removed the extra svg between the 2 charts. Here is the [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/urd3oIP0G2xwsTkSUTOx?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks FernOfTheAndes.

Comment: I have tried creating a second data file named datam.csv here http://plnkr.co/edit/QPpzfkyd7FMdPuA312Aq?p=catalogue is this the correct way of declaring datam.csv ?

Comment: @user3438326 You need to add `});` to the very end of the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is hopefully the final [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KW8qH7u3hJy1g4qQNI8n?p=preview) in this ever-growing project :) (A lot of the csv work here has been guided by the great Lars...as usual, many kudos to him.)

[Updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KW8qH7u3hJy1g4qQNI8n?p=preview) with data on top chart coming from datam.csv.

Comment: FernOfTheAndes the data.csv is loading properly whereas the datam.csv is not loading i.e. the chart on the top is taking the values of data.csv itself. I want the chart on top to take datam.csv values.

Comment: @user3438326 Yes, `data(datam)` was the fix for that. I have updated the response with the revised plunker. See above.

Comment: FernOfTheAndes thank you so much. You are Awesome :)

Comment: FernOfTheAndes - Consider this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/QPpzfkyd7FMdPuA312Aq?p=preview. In this plunker I have added one more file datan.csv, also one more column to data.csv-named third. I want the chart to be plotted according the Enumerated order from data.csv file, in the data.csv file first denotes X-axis, second denotes number of Y units and third denotes the text which should be sorted according to the order of enumerated data. How to do this ?

Comment: FernOfTheAndes can you help with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22861768/sorting-of-array-and-plotting-the-chart ?